# Function to convert binary tree to full Binary tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

The implementation for Binary tree is given below.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.right = None
        self.left = None


root = Node(5)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(7)
root.left.left.left = Node(9)
root.right.right = Node(1)
root.right.right.right = Node(6)
root.right.right.left = Node(4)
```

As given in image tree is not a full binary tree. How to write a function to convert above binary tree to full binary tree by just adding string data nodes to the node which does not have child nodes to make full binary tree.

Manualy I will add nodes in the code to get the resultant tree like this:

```py
root.left.right = Node('a')
root.right.left = Node('a')
root.right.left.left = Node('a')
root.right.left.right = Node('a')
root.left.right.right = Node('a')
root.left.right.left = Node('a')
```

But how to write a function which will take root node and return tree which is full binary tree.

[image: binary tree which is not a full binary tree]
[image: full binary tree in which new nodes are added with char value]

Comment: Shouldn't the node 7 have been given another child to make the tree full?

Comment: Yes. i forgot to mention. i will uodate the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a method that can give you the maximum depth in you tree.  From that you can add a method to recursively add empty nodes down to that depth:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

    @property
    def maxDepth(self): # compute maximum depth (i.e. levels under self)
        depth = 0
        if self.left:  depth = self.left.maxDepth+1
        if self.right: depth = max(depth,self.right.maxDepth+1)
        return depth

    def expandToDepth(self,depth=None): # add empty nodes to fill tree
        if depth is None: depth = self.maxDepth
        if not depth: return
        if not self.left:  self.left  = Node(None)
        if not self.right: self.right = Node(None)
        self.left.expandToDepth(depth-1)
        self.right.expandToDepth(depth-1)

    def __repr__(self): # this is just to print the tree
        nodeInfo = lambda n: (str(n.data or "?"),n.left,n.right)
        return "\n".join(printBTree(self,nodeInfo,isTop=False))
```

output:

```
root = Node(5)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(7)
root.left.left.left = Node(9)
root.right.right = Node(1)
root.right.right.right = Node(6)
root.right.right.left = Node(4)

## BEFORE ##
print(root)

      5
     / \
    2   3
   /     \
  7       1
 /       / \
9       4   6

root.expandToDepth()

## AFTER ##
print(root)

             5
       _____/ \_____
      2             3
   __/ \_        __/ \_
  7      ?      ?      1
 / \    / \    / \    / \
9   ?  ?   ?  ?   ?  4   6
```

**printBTree()** is a function I provided as an answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844237/5237560

Here is a copy of it (in case the link disappears):

```
import functools as fn

def printBTree(node, nodeInfo=None, inverted=False, isTop=True):

       # node value string and sub nodes
       stringValue, leftNode, rightNode = nodeInfo(node)

       stringValueWidth  = len(stringValue)

       # recurse to sub nodes to obtain line blocks on left and right
       leftTextBlock     = [] if not leftNode else printBTree(leftNode,nodeInfo,inverted,False)

       rightTextBlock    = [] if not rightNode else printBTree(rightNode,nodeInfo,inverted,False)

       # count common and maximum number of sub node lines
       commonLines       = min(len(leftTextBlock),len(rightTextBlock))
       subLevelLines     = max(len(rightTextBlock),len(leftTextBlock))

       # extend lines on shallower side to get same number of lines on both sides
       leftSubLines      = leftTextBlock  + [""] *  (subLevelLines - len(leftTextBlock))
       rightSubLines     = rightTextBlock + [""] *  (subLevelLines - len(rightTextBlock))

       # compute location of value or link bar for all left and right sub nodes
       #   * left node's value ends at line's width
       #   * right node's value starts after initial spaces
       leftLineWidths    = [ len(line) for line in leftSubLines  ]                            
       rightLineIndents  = [ len(line)-len(line.lstrip(" ")) for line in rightSubLines ]

       # top line value locations, will be used to determine position of current node & link bars
       firstLeftWidth    = (leftLineWidths   + [0])[0]  
       firstRightIndent  = (rightLineIndents + [0])[0] 

       # width of sub node link under node value (i.e. with slashes if any)
       # aims to center link bars under the value if value is wide enough
       # 
       # ValueLine:    v     vv    vvvvvv   vvvvv
       # LinkLine:    / \   /  \    /  \     / \ 
       #
       linkSpacing       = min(stringValueWidth, 2 - stringValueWidth % 2)
       leftLinkBar       = 1 if leftNode  else 0
       rightLinkBar      = 1 if rightNode else 0
       minLinkWidth      = leftLinkBar + linkSpacing + rightLinkBar
       valueOffset       = (stringValueWidth - linkSpacing) // 2

       # find optimal position for right side top node
       #   * must allow room for link bars above and between left and right top nodes
       #   * must not overlap lower level nodes on any given line (allow gap of minSpacing)
       #   * can be offset to the left if lower subNodes of right node 
       #     have no overlap with subNodes of left node                                                                                                                                 
       minSpacing        = 2
       rightNodePosition = fn.reduce(lambda r,i: max(r,i[0] + minSpacing + firstRightIndent - i[1]), \
                                     zip(leftLineWidths,rightLineIndents[0:commonLines]), \
                                     firstLeftWidth + minLinkWidth)

       # extend basic link bars (slashes) with underlines to reach left and right
       # top nodes.  
       #
       #        vvvvv
       #       __/ \__
       #      L       R
       #
       linkExtraWidth    = max(0, rightNodePosition - firstLeftWidth - minLinkWidth )
       rightLinkExtra    = linkExtraWidth // 2
       leftLinkExtra     = linkExtraWidth - rightLinkExtra

       # build value line taking into account left indent and link bar extension (on left side)
       valueIndent       = max(0, firstLeftWidth + leftLinkExtra + leftLinkBar - valueOffset)
       valueLine         = " " * max(0,valueIndent) + stringValue
       slash             = "\\" if inverted else  "/"
       backslash         = "/" if inverted else  "\\"
       uLine             = "¯" if inverted else  "_"

       # build left side of link line
       leftLink          = "" if not leftNode else ( " " * firstLeftWidth + uLine * leftLinkExtra + slash)

       # build right side of link line (includes blank spaces under top node value) 
       rightLinkOffset   = linkSpacing + valueOffset * (1 - leftLinkBar)                      
       rightLink         = "" if not rightNode else ( " " * rightLinkOffset + backslash + uLine * rightLinkExtra )

       # full link line (will be empty if there are no sub nodes)                                                                                                    
       linkLine          = leftLink + rightLink

       # will need to offset left side lines if right side sub nodes extend beyond left margin
       # can happen if left subtree is shorter (in height) than right side subtree                                                
       leftIndentWidth   = max(0,firstRightIndent - rightNodePosition) 
       leftIndent        = " " * leftIndentWidth
       indentedLeftLines = [ (leftIndent if line else "") + line for line in leftSubLines ]

       # compute distance between left and right sublines based on their value position
       # can be negative if leading spaces need to be removed from right side
       mergeOffsets      = [ len(line) for line in indentedLeftLines ]
       mergeOffsets      = [ leftIndentWidth + rightNodePosition - firstRightIndent - w for w in mergeOffsets ]
       mergeOffsets      = [ p if rightSubLines[i] else 0 for i,p in enumerate(mergeOffsets) ]

       # combine left and right lines using computed offsets
       #   * indented left sub lines
       #   * spaces between left and right lines
       #   * right sub line with extra leading blanks removed.
       mergedSubLines    = zip(range(len(mergeOffsets)), mergeOffsets, indentedLeftLines)
       mergedSubLines    = [ (i,p,line + (" " * max(0,p)) )       for i,p,line in mergedSubLines ]
       mergedSubLines    = [ line + rightSubLines[i][max(0,-p):]  for i,p,line in mergedSubLines ]                        

       # Assemble final result combining
       #  * node value string
       #  * link line (if any)
       #  * merged lines from left and right sub trees (if any)
       treeLines = [leftIndent + valueLine] + ( [] if not linkLine else [leftIndent + linkLine] ) + mergedSubLines

       # invert final result if requested
       treeLines = reversed(treeLines) if inverted and isTop else treeLines

       # return intermediate tree lines or print final result
       if isTop : print("\n".join(treeLines))
       else     : return treeLines
```

Comment: important method here is expandToDepth which fills the other nodes, where printBTree function helps to visualize actual tree. Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the height of the tree. That will be the height of the full tree. Next, traverse the tree and, for each node, if its depth is less than the height of the tree and it is missing either its left or right child (or both), add what is missing, and continue traversing. So for your input the process would go

```
5             h=0
=> 2          h=1
   => 7       h=2
     => 9     h=3
=> 3          h=1
   => 1       h=2
      => 4    h=3
      => 6    h=3

max height seen was 3, so height of tree is 3

5             h < 3, has both children, nothing to add
=> 2          h < 3, missing right child, add 'a'
   => 7       h < 3, missing right child, add 'b'
      => 9    h = 3, nothing to add
      => b    h = 3, nothing to add
   => a       h < 3, missing left and right children, add 'c' and 'd'
      => c    h = 3, nothing to add
      => d    h = 3, nothing to add
=> 3          h < 3, missing left child, add 'e'
   => e       h < 3, missing left and right children, add 'f' and 'g'
      => f    h = 3, nothing to add
      => g    h = 3, nothing to add
   => 1       h < 3, has both children, nothing to add
      => 4    h = 3, nothing to add
      => 6    h = 3, nothing to add
```

So we see that this adds the same nodes you did by hand (you actually might have missed one, 7 only has one child in your drawing). We labeled them a, b, c, d, e, f and g, but you could write the code so it gives them all the same string.