# How to display a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to display a binary search tree in Python using the _displayRec method below. However, when I test it with a simple example, the display becomes unbalanced on the right side:

```
def display(self):
        print("Displaying tree:")
        print("----------------")
        lines, *_ = self._displayRec(self._root)
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
        print("----------------")

    def _displayRec(self, node):
        if node is None:
            line = "Empty"
            width = len(line)
            height = 1
            middle = width // 2
            return [line], width, height, middle
        else:
            key = str(node.getKey())
            value = str(node.getValue())
            label = f"{key} ({value})"
            left_lines, left_width, left_height, left_middle = self._displayRec(node.getLeft())
            right_lines, right_width, right_height, right_middle = self._displayRec(node.getRight())
            node_label = label
            node_label_width = len(node_label)
            first_line = (left_middle + 1) * " " + (left_width // 2) * "_" + node_label + (right_width // 2) * "_"
            second_line = left_middle * " " + "/" + (left_middle + node_label_width + right_middle) * " " + "\\" + (right_width - right_middle - 1) * " "
            if left_height < right_height:
                left_lines += [left_width * " "] * (right_height - left_height)
            elif right_height < left_height:
                right_lines += [right_width * " "] * (left_height - right_height)
            zipped_lines = zip(left_lines, right_lines)
            lines = [first_line, second_line] + [a + " " * (node_label_width + 1) + b for a, b in zipped_lines]
            width = left_width + node_label_width + right_width + 1
            height = max(left_height, right_height) + 2
            middle = width // 2
            return lines, width, height, middle
```

Here's the code I'm using to test the display method:

```
tree.insert(4, "four")
tree.insert(5, "five")
tree.insert(1, "one")
tree.insert(2, "two")
tree.insert(3, "three")
tree.display()
```

The resulting display looks like this:

```
Inserted key 4 with value four
Inserted key 5 with value five
Inserted key 1 with value one
Inserted key 2 with value two
Inserted key 3 with value three
Displaying tree:
----------------
                        _______________________4 (four)_________
                       /                                        \
   __1 (one)________________            __5 (five)__
  /                         \                           /            \
Empty           __2 (two)__________         Empty         Empty
               /                   \
             Empty           __3 (three)__
                            /             \
                          Empty          Empty
----------------
```

As you can see, the right side of the display is unbalanced and difficult to read. How can I modify the _displayRec method to fix this issue and make the tree display balanced?

Comment: Please explain your logic for computing the number of spaces to print between nodes.

Comment: Look at this answer for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844237/5237560

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems is that your lines are not equally sized. All of the following expressions should be the same value, but they are different:

- `len(first_line)`
- `len(second_line)`
- `left_width + node_label_width + 1 + right_width`

I took a slightly different approach where the returned lines include an extra line with the upwards edge "/", and then it is up to the caller to change that to a backslash or to throw it away (in case it is the initial call).

The use of the `.center()` and `.rjust()` string methods makes some expressions easier.

This version will not have the problem you encountered:

```
    def display(self):
        print("Displaying tree:")
        print("----------------")
        lines = self._displayRec(self._root)[1:]
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
        print("----------------")

    def _displayRec(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return [
                "   /   ",
                " Empty "
            ]
        else:
            left_lines = self._displayRec(node.getLeft())
            right_lines = self._displayRec(node.getRight())
            right_lines[0] = right_lines[0].replace("/", "\\")

            label = f"{node.getKey()} ({node.getValue()})"
            label_width = len(label)
            label_offset = left_lines[0].index("/") + 1
            available_label_width = len(left_lines[0]) + right_lines[0].index("\\") - label_offset
            gap = max(0, label_width - available_label_width)
            available_label_width += gap
            width = len(left_lines[0]) + gap + len(right_lines[0])

            diff = len(left_lines) - len(right_lines) 
            if diff < 0:
                left_lines += [len(left_lines[0]) * " "] * (-diff)
            elif diff > 0:
                right_lines += [len(right_lines[0]) * " "] * diff
            return [
                (" " * label_offset + "/".center(available_label_width)).ljust(width),
                (" " * label_offset + label.center(available_label_width, "_")).ljust(width)
            ] + [a + " " * gap + b for a, b in zip(left_lines, right_lines)]
```